# Finding the average age of users with 0 posts, 1-5 posts, and >5 posts

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, aggregate-functions

I need to generate a report on the age of some of our users with respect to their post count grouped by their country of residence.

Here's a simplified version of my schema right now:

```
DESCRIBE countries;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

DESCRIBE users;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| age        | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

DESCRIBE posts;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I'd like a result set that looks something like this:

```
country.name | AVG(age of users with 0 posts) | AVG(age of users with 1-5 posts | AVG(age of users with 1-5 posts
----------------------------------------
Denmark  | 17.4   | 23.2   | NULL
Germany  | 20.1   | 27.8   | 34.7
England  | 31.1   | NULL   | 28.3
```

where NULL would represent a country who has no users at a particular post-count level. For example, everyone in Denmark has 0 through 5 posts, and no more. I suppose it doesn't have to say NULL, but it should be clear that this value is undetermined.

So far, this is my query:

```
SELECT
    c.name,
    AVG(something) AS avg_age_with_no_posts,
    AVG(something) AS `avg_age_with_1-5_posts`,
    AVG(something) AS `avg_age_with_gt5_posts`
FROM
    users u
    JOIN posts p ON p.user_id=u.id
    JOIN countries c ON c.id=u.country_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

I know it's not much, but I've actually foiled with other clauses (nested selects, HAVING, COUNT(CASE ... WHEN ...)) quite a bit (several hours). The query above is just the fundamental things I know I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 Select c.name,
    Avg(Case When pc.postCount == 0 Then pc.Age End) avgAgeNoPosts,
    Avg(Case When pc.postCount Between 1 And 5 Then pc.Age End) avgAge1_5Posts,
    Avg(Case When pc.postCount > 5 Age End) Then pc.Age End) avgAgeGT5Posts
 From users u
    Join countries c On c.id=u.country_id
    Join (Select user_id uid, Count(*) postCount
          From posts
          Group By user_id ) pc
       On pc.UId = u.id
 Group By c.name
```

To explain why the `Sum(Case When ... End)` expression works without an else, when none of the options specified in When clauses are true, will output a null.  And all the aggregation operators  (including Sum() ), will ignore nulls.

Comment: Rogue `END)` on line 4.  Would also be useful to explain how/why this works.  *(Such as AVG({1,2,3,NULL}) doesn't include the `NULL` in the calculation.)*